# $\sigma$-compactness of some locally compact Hausdorff topological groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry, topological-groups, topological-vector-spaces

> Is the topological group $(\mathbf{Q}_p/\mathbf{Z}_p)^{\oplus k}$, $k\ge 1$, a $\sigma$-compact topological group when endowed with its natural $p$-adic topology?

More generally, I'm looking for a criterion for locally compact Hausdorff topological groups to not contain a nested exhaustive sequence of compact subgroups (i.e. locally compact Hausdorff topological groups $G$ with a countable family of nested compact subsets $K_n$ such that $\bigcup_{n\ge 0}K_n = G$).

**Example** Real and complex Lie groups are $\sigma$-compact exactly when they are compact.

**Example** The same group $(\mathbf{Q}_p/\mathbf{Z}_p)^{\oplus k}$, endowed with the discrete topology. It is uncountable, so it's not $\sigma$-compact when endowed with the discrete topology, if I'm not missing anything.

Comment: A second comment: I think [$\sigma$-compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-compact_space) means a union of compact _subspaces_, which seems very different to an increasing sequence of compact _subgroups_.    I think many non-compact Lie groups are $\sigma$-compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @MatthewDaws ... for example the real Lie group $(\mathbb R,+)$ with the usual topology is locally compact and sigma-compact but not compact.

Take any locally compact group $G$.  There is a neighborhood $V$ of $e$ with compact closure.  The subgroup $H$ generated by $V$ is an open, locally compact, sigma-compact subgroup of $G$.  The coset space $G/H$ is discrete.

---

The example.  The group $\mathbb Q_p$ of $p$-adic numbers is locally compact.  The subgroup $\mathbb Z_p$ of $p$-adic integers is an open, compact, subgroup.  The quotient $\mathbb Q_p/\mathbb Z_p$ is countable and discrete.

Indeed,
$$
\mathbb Q_p = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty p^n \mathbb Z_p .
$$

For a fixed $k \in \mathbb N$, also $(\mathbf{Q}_p/\mathbf{Z}_p)^{\oplus k}$ is countable and discrete.

Comment: Yes, I understand. You're of course correct. Thanks